# Top panel doesn't stay above windows

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

I made as small (16% width) top panel. It suddenly gets hidden behind overlapping or maximized windows. Neither '...panel as dock', 'Reserve space...', nor automatic hiding are checked.

How do I make it stay on top?

I already tried creating a new one, but the problem remained.

Comment: Lucky you... I'm looking everywhere to find a way to disable the "always on top" panel behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make lxpanel stay above other windows you should:

1. in panel settings:

   - Make window managers treat panel as dock
   - Reserve space and not covered by maximized windows
2. in Openbox Settings (obconf from console) in Dock section set all appropriate settings.